# Options for storing thousands of records (available offline) with iOS/Phonegap

Tags: ios, core-data, cordova

I need some guidance for storing 600K-900K records, and make them available offline (within the app).

According to [this](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/ios/data-management.html), it could be based on Core Data, however I was wondering if PhoneGap or some plugin provides any viable solutions. I'm trying to avoid coding in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to so would be to create a pre-populated sqlite db and copy it to the correct location the first time your app starts up.

http://gauravstomar.blogspot.ca/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+GauravSTomarBootstrappingIntelligence+(Gaurav+S+Tomar+:+Bootstrapping+Intelligence)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess it would need to be overwritten all-over again, whenever I need to add new records to the db (when the user comes online).